# What are return types of operators in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am reading the C++ Primer, in the overloaded operation chapter, the author gave an example:

```
// member binary operator: left-hand operand bound to implicit this pointer
Sales_item& Sales_item::operator+=(const Sales_item&);
// nonmember binary operator: must declare a parameter for each operand
Sales_item operator+(const Sales_item&, const Sales_item&);
```

then, the author explained:

> This difference matches the return types of these operators when applied to arithmetic types: Addition yields an rvalue and compound assignment returns a reference to the left-hand operand.

I'm not quite sure about "`compound assignment returns a reference to the left-hand operand`". Can anyone elaborate on that, and relevant things, please?

Comment: Look up method chaining. It basically means `a = b` returns `a` so that `c = a = b` evaluates to `c = (a = b)` or `a = b` then `c = a` all in 1 statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that you can do something like the following

```
a = 1; 
(a += 1) += 1;
```

and the result will be a == 3.  This is because the left most call to += modifies `a` and then 
 returns a reference to it.  Then the next += operates on the reference to `a` and again adds a number to it.

On the other hand, the normal + operator returns a *copy* of the result, not a reference to one of the arguments.  So this means that an expression such as `a + a = 3;` is illegal.

Comment: @Robᵩ: He is surely sure about that. But that doesn't mean he is correct. -1 for wrong answer.

Comment: @Nawaz: I find the downvote a little harsh, since it's solved with [just a pair of parentheses](http://ideone.com/hdhf1). The essence of compound assignment has been captured in the answer, so failing Davis because he tripped on a simple issue (artifact of the whiteboard) seems a tad hard.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Doesn't that *modify* `a` twice without any intervening sequence point? Which in others means, doesn't it invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: @Nawaz, no, it's just two successive calls to the OP's Sales_item::operator+=() routine.  This is just as valid as any other construct such as obj.funct().another().

Comment: @DavisKing: The data type in your example is `int` which doesn't has `operator+=` as function;in other words, the expression `(a+=1)` doesn't introduce any sequence point (*as far as I know*).

Comment: @Nawaz, I mean for `a` to have the Sales_item type and I'm assuming it can be constructed from an int to make the example simpler.  But as for int, I'm not sure if += alone introduces a sequence point or if it's necessary to have an intervening `;`.  We could break the statement up and put in explicit references like `int& rval = (a+=1); rval += 1;` but I think that makes the answer more confusing.

Comment: @DavisKing: Your answer is already confusing. You should take `Sales_item` and then should explain what you wanted to explain.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = a + b;
```

is also

```
a += b;
```

which is equivalent to

```
a.operator+= (b)
```

operator += supports compound assignment:

```
(a += b) += c;
```

is equivalent to

```
a.operator+= (b).operator+= (c);
```

The last line would not be possible if a value was returned instead of an rvalue.

Consider the following:

```
c = a + b;
```

is also

```
c = a.operator+ (b);
```

writing

```
a.operator+ (b) = c;
```

has no effect because the value of a is not changed.